# "HTTP status 404 - Not Found" while running in tomcat

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat, web-applications, http-error

Description: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
I am developing a simple Spring MVC project using the Tomcat server, but when I running it on the server it's landing to HTTP 404 not found.

[image]

It is my Controller code

[image]

It is my view code
[image]

.. servlet.xml file
[image]

web.xml file
[image]

Deployment Assembly
[image]

Tomcat ports
[image]

I tired to fix it but no use.Please help me out....

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix by looking at dependency assembly, ports, etc., lol..
But I specified the base package wrongly in spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml

I am trying to fix it by a day, just after posting the question I am looking at the files, At a glance, I found it... hurry :)
[image]